# Difference between mysql_data_seek and mysql_field_seek?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I found that both of them are doing the same job. Is there any difference or not. I think, I had missed something.

**mysql_data_seek**

```
<?php


    $sql="SELECT  * from testing";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
    echo $row->id . ' ' . $row->name; // Output is (1      Hassan)
    mysql_data_seek($result,2);
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
    echo $row->id . ' ' . $row->name; // Output is (3      Rose)
    echo "<BR><BR>";
?>
```

**mysql_field_seek**

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("sql.server.com", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 
$sql="SELECT  * from table1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['ID'] . ' ' . $row['Name']; // Output is (1      Hassan)
mysql_field_seek($result,2);
echo $row['ID'] . ' ' . $row['Name']; // Output is (3      Rose)
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_data_seek - moves to a specific row of the dataset
mysql_field_seek - moves to a specific column of current row of the dataset
```

Actually the answer to your question [is in the same page from which you copied this question](https://www.php.net/mysql_field_seek)